# Appending Matlab Data from metcdf file

Tags: matlab, matrix, append, netcdf

I've been working on this for a while now...I have netcdf data that is in the form of 684x447x72 for each netcdf file I read using ncread(path,myvarname,[1 1 1], [684 447 72]).  I need to append the data in dimension 3 for file = 2 to make the variable now 684x447x144 and so on for each new file.  So, for example if I have 10 files, then the final read_in_var = 684x447x720.  How do I do this within a loop reading one file at a time?  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Use [matrix indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html).
Considering the filenames are file1, file2, file3,... file10, the following will work:

```
read_in_var = zeros(684,447,720);   %Pre-allocation
for k=1:10
    read_in_var(:,:,72*(k-1)+1:72*k)) = ncread(['file',num2str(k),'.nc'], ...
        myvarname,[1 1 1], [684 447 72]);
end
```

Comment: hi - thanks for your answer but this method still does not solve my memory problem as I load these files.  As I progress to read netcdf data, my program using your method or mine (slightly faster using a vertical concatenation from the 4th dimension of file number or "k" and moving that to the 3rd dimension in read_in_var(:,:,72*k) runs slower and slower and takes all my RAM on my desktop in the meantime.  any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by *" does not solve*"? You didn't mention any memory problem before. If you're not interested in keeping the data of all the iterations then discard them. Why ask about *appending*? If you want to keep all that data then it will definitely be taking some memory and that cannot be avoided unless you save some of the data to the disk and load later if you want to use. Without you explaining what exactly you're dealing with inside that loop, nothing can be suggested